# Debugging arcpy.da.UpdateCursor where clause which gives RuntimeError: Cannot find field?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, cursor, runtimeerror

I'm trying to use UpdateCursor in arcpy, but the where clause I'm using seems to be causing trouble. However, when I open up the table in ArcMap and use Select By Attributes with the exact same clause that causes an error in the Python script, it works fine.

The name of a feature class and a dictionary containing strings is passed into a function with the following code:

```
rows = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(featureClass, "{0} = {1}".format("PropCode", "'"+hotelDict["hotelId"]+"'"))
for row in rows:
    print "stuff" #I just wanted to see if it was making it here
```

I get the following error: `RuntimeError: Cannot find field 'PropCode = 'FR066''`

More info that may or may not be helpful: I'm using ArcGIS 10.1, the field that is being searched in contains text, and using `arcpy.AddFiedlDelimiters(featureClass, "PropCode")` instead of just `"PropCode"` did not fix the problem.

There are no results from Googling "RuntimeError: Cannot find field", and `PropCode = 'FR066'` is correct when using Select By Attributes in ArcMap, so I'm kind of stumped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the API wrong. `arcpy.da`'s second argument is a list of fields, not a where clause. Did you mean:

```
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(featureClass,
                               ['*'],
                               "{0} = '{1}'".format("PropCode",       
                                                    hotelDict["hotelId"]))
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I was accidentally looking at the 10.0 reference when I was figuring out parameters.

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS expects field names to be bounded by the double quote character: `"` Of course, this is also the same character in Python that separates strings. To make Python not end a string when it encounters a double quote, you need to use the backslash escape character: `\`. So your cursor expression will look like this:

```
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(featureClass, "\"PropCode\" = '"+hotelDict["hotelId"]+"'")
```

With this, the second and third double quotes are ignored by Python, and your expression is successfully passed into ArcGIS.

Comment: I think the delimiters for field names actually depend on how the data is stored, and in this case double quotes aren't necessary. Thank you though!

Comment: This answer is referring to arcpy.UpdateCursor() while the question is about arcpy.da.UpdateCursor().